# Values are out of order in ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my original data frame, called `e`:

```
structure(list(`Variance (2)` = c(48.4127, 5.28412698412698, 0.00520833333333333, 0.72083903433112), `Variance (4)` = c(42.0635, 11.7253968253968, 0.0164803125616411, 0.757277684759935), `Variance & Mean (2)` = c(73.8095, 8.63095238095238, 0.0292019422400468, 0.633561928614755), `Variance & Mean (4)` = c(28.5714, 33.4107142857143, 0.0258761022200942, 0.496305437129809), `Radar Only (2)` = c(73.8095, 18.3043650793651, 0.0923386443151634, 0.435493681015241), `Radar Only (4)` = c(51.5873, 76.5388888888889, 0.0563903328454791, 0.402952149580986), `All Data(2)` = c(73.8095, 36.3634920634921, 0.0717603398435939, 0.296927697111903), `All Data(3)` = c(69.8413, 52.168253968254, 0.065214418675562, 0.300126336907244), `All Data Scaled(2)` = c(64.2857, 52.1623015873016, 0.0657912811602958, 0.247276928682524), `All Data Scaled(4)` = c(67.4603, 84.1174603174603, 0.0380569462508109, 0.257546088468624)), .Names = c("Variance (2)", "Variance (4)", "Variance & Mean (2)", "Variance & Mean (4)", "Radar Only (2)", "Radar Only (4)", "All Data(2)", "All Data(3)", "All Data Scaled(2)", "All Data Scaled(4)"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

- I'm building a heat map from this data frame
- Colors should be determined by scaled values
- Labels should be original values
- Something went wrong while building a melted data frame

Here's the code I have so far:

```
f<-e
f<-t(f)    # transpose so we can scale
f<-apply(f,c(1,2),function(x) as.numeric(x)) # make numeric, cuz this factors them for some reason
f<-scale(f)
f<-t(f)    # transpose again to get in meltable format
rownames(f)<-c("Specificity","Connectivity","Dunn Index","Silhouette")

# A & C are better if they're higher, so I separate them out.
hi<-as.matrix(f[c("Specificity","Dunn Index"),])

oh<-melt(t(e[c(1,3),]))    # get the original values

hi.m <- melt(hi)
hi.m <- cbind(hi.m,oh[,3]) # cbind the original vals to scaled !!! ISSUE HERE !!!!
colnames(hi.m)[4]<-"ovals"
```

**So at this point the data has become unordered, and I'm not sure why.**

---

Here's the code for the plot:

```
ggplot(hi.m, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_label(aes(label = round(ovals,4)),fill="white",alpha=0.65) +
  scale_fill_viridis(name="Scaled\nValue",option="plasma")
```

Here's an image of what's going on. The red arrows indicate where that data should be:
[image]

---

Edit: Clarification.

There was some confusion about how the final product should look so I will include this to help:

The data should look like this:

```
              "Specificity" "Dunn Index"
Variance (2)        48.4127 0.005208333 
Variance (4)        42.0635 0.016480313 
Variance & Mean (2) 73.8095 0.029201942 
Variance & Mean (4) 28.5714 0.025876102 
Radar Only (2)      73.8095 0.092338644 
Radar Only (4)      51.5873 0.056390333 
All Data(2)         73.8095 0.071760340 
All Data(3)         69.8413 0.065214419 
All Data Scaled(2)  64.2857 0.065791281 
All Data Scaled(4)  67.4603 0.038056946
```

Specificity is between 27 and 74, and Dunn Index is between 0 and 1.

Comment: The comments in the code make no sense to me. The values already are numeric and none of the operations make them factors, ... and it's not true that "A and C are higher". There should be no need to apply `as.matrix` to t(f). It's been a matrix all along ever since the first `t(f)`. The meaning or identity of these items might help understand what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

(I wasn't clear exactly what the error was but chose to focus on the chart rather than the result of the `melt`, since you spent so much effort on that diagram. If it's really the result of the `melt` that is "wrong", then you should strip out all the stuff about the ggplot2 effort.)

I can reproduce the chart, but I don't think there was an error. I took your dataset and did `xtabs` on the `ovals`-values which are the numeric labels:

```
 xtabs( ovals ~ Var2 +Var1, data=hi.m)
                     Var1
Var2                             A            C
  Variance (2)        48.412700000 42.063500000
  Variance (4)        73.809500000 28.571400000
  Variance & Mean (2) 73.809500000 51.587300000
  Variance & Mean (4) 73.809500000 69.841300000
  Radar Only (2)      64.285700000 67.460300000
  Radar Only (4)       0.005208333  0.016480313
  All Data(2)          0.029201942  0.025876102
  All Data(3)          0.092338644  0.056390333
  All Data Scaled(2)   0.071760340  0.065214419
  All Data Scaled(4)   0.065791281  0.038056946
```

Thats essentially what you are seeing only with the row order reveresed. Yo get teh values in the order you wnated, you coudl reverse teh levels of the factor:

```
> v2rlevs <- rev(levels(hi.m$Var2))
> hi.m$newV2 <- factor( as.character(hi.m$Var2), levels= v2rlevs)
> xtabs( ovals ~ newV2 +Var1, data=hi.m)
                     Var1
newV2                            A            C
  All Data Scaled(4)   0.065791281  0.038056946
  All Data Scaled(2)   0.071760340  0.065214419
  All Data(3)          0.092338644  0.056390333
  All Data(2)          0.029201942  0.025876102
  Radar Only (4)       0.005208333  0.016480313
  Radar Only (2)      64.285700000 67.460300000
  Variance & Mean (4) 73.809500000 69.841300000
  Variance & Mean (2) 73.809500000 51.587300000
  Variance (4)        73.809500000 28.571400000
  Variance (2)        48.412700000 42.063500000
```

(Which is the reversal of the default ordering used by ggplot2 since it starts at the "top" and goes down. If you want your chart "flipped" on the "row-axis" which is waht I *think* is being requested, you only need to use the `newV2`.

[image]

Comment: Please see my update, I guess I didn't explain the problem very well. But basically the big issue wasn't that the values were upside down, it's that they were literally in the wrong order. In the data I'm mapping that's wrong, all the big numbers came first, then the little numbers. It should be `[big number, little number]` for each row.

Comment: With reference to the 'e' object: The "big numbers" were in rows 1 and 2. The "little numbers" were in rows 3 and 4. You were the one that grouped rows 1 and 3 together. that mixes "big" and "little" in your terminology. Using more meaningful names for these columns in the original object could clarify this question.

Comment: OK, but yeah, that's the issue is that these numbers got mixed together incorrectly. I'll add real names to the columns. Thanks!

Comment: OK I added better names. `Specificity` is a percentage, and all the values are between 27 - 74. `Dunn Index` values are between 0 - 1. But, this isn't really a ggplot issue, it's more of "How to plot a dataframe as a heatmap" issue, ya know?